# How is x++==4 a condition?

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements, logical-operators, edx

I was taking a java course on edx. For this question, the condition is x++==4. I tried and found out that only when i enter an x value of 4, the condition evaluates to true. But why?

1) Why is it that when i enter x = 3 or x = 2 the condition evaluates to false?

2) Why is x++==4 even a condition? it's like x = x + 4. How can it ever be true or false? It is an equation, not like x > 3 etc.

[image]

Comment: `x++==4` is not like `x = x + 4`.

Comment: look up `++` unary operator and `==`.

Comment: why should it *not* be a condition? *"It is an equation"* - **no**, there is a `==`.

Comment: `x = x + 4` is _not_ an equation. It is an assignment expression-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (x++==4) { ... }
```

could simply be replace by the following lines

```
boolean b = (x == 4);
x = x + 1;
if (b) { ... }
```

You evaluate if `x` is equals to `4` and then increment it using the [Postfix increment Operator ++](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)

---

> Why is it that when i enter x = 3 or x = 2 the condition evaluates to
>   false?

Because

```
3 == 4; // false
2 == 4; // false
```

Comment: You should slightly expand your code; it wouldn't currently compile because `x == 4` isn't a statement etc. I will suggest an edit to make your statement more accurate (feel free to roll back if you disagree). (Not the downvoter)

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the edit, it's clearer indeed. I don't mind the downvotes.. As long as the answer is correct

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm wondering if it should be boolean b = (x == 4);
if (b) { ... }
x = x + 1;     since it's a postfix increment.

Comment: @vade No since you're boolean evaluation is done at `boolean b = (x == 4)` and you incrementation should happen just after the evaluation.

Comment: Yea i did but it said i need 15 reps for my vote to appear publicly

Answer (score 0):

It is because `x==4` IS a condition? therfore x++ is just an increment on the value if the variable

Dont let the ++ to trick your mind...

the same can happen even on ugliest ways like

`if (x---5==0) {` which just happens to be

```
   if ((x--)-5==0) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So your example is equivalent if (x==5) { }  then later     x = x - 1 ?

Comment: yes... for the sake of the example that is the point I want yo to get....

Comment: soon or latter you will check, that is not a good idea because of the overflows can break the hole condition ...